# What is the human unreadable in a stream obj of the uncompressed PDF

Tags: pdf, qpdf

As It's supposed to be uncompressed by

```
qpdf i.pdf --stream-data=uncompress o.pdf
```

but then there's still some sequential lines which is human unreadable in some stream objects

So confused what it is actually or usually,
so what is `qpdf` CLI to have a "100% real" uncompressed one?

Comment: PDF is a mixture of text and binary parts; the textual parts of which can (mostly) be compressed (and thus appear binary). This is not a 100% binary file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams in PDF can contain either text or binary information. Examples:

- XMP information: textual
- Font: binary
- Page description: textual
- Image: binary

What happens when you uncompress them, is that you get the uncompressed data, but this uncompressed data is then either textual or binary depending on what the stream is used for.